# How is the std::map::max_size() return calculated?

Tags: c++, dictionary, containers, stdmap, max-size

I have the following map:

```
std::map<int, std::string> map;
```

and my output when i call:

```
std::cout << map.max_size() << std::endl;
```

is 128102389400760775 on my linux system(wsl2). I am searching for an alternative way to reach this result without std::numerical_limits.

So far i came up with the following wrong approach, which worked for vector:

```
std::map<int, std::string>::allocator_type a_type_map;
std::cout << a_type_map.max_size() << std::endl;
```

Probably it has something to do with the Nodes, which take additional storage or something.

Comment: The C++ standard does not specify how it is calculated.

Comment: don't use `max_size()`, it's pretty much useless.  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This is the max size assuming your computer has enough memory, which it doesn't, and which it likely never will. That's 128x10^15 entries, or at 8 bytes per entry, 1 *exabyte* of memory.

Comment: *I am searching for an alternative way to reach this result without std::numerical_limits.* -- This is turning into an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Minor note: Your final sentence is generally considered somewhere between [irrelevant and rude](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest). We know you want an answer, that's why you asked the question.

Comment: alright i figured it out... to get max_sizeyou need to type: (size_t(-1) / sizeof(std::map<Key, mapped_type>)) / 3). Ps.: @PaulMcKenzie you come close with your assumption, the purpose of figuring this out serves just to lie about a max_size() i have in my own map implementation

Comment: *'I am searching for an alternative way to reach this result without `std::numerical_limits`.'* -- Maybe explain why?

Comment: @Imarquar `max_size()` returns the maximum number of elements the `std::map` can physically hold. You don't want to divide `size_t(-1)` by the size of `std::map` itself, but rather by the size of an individual element, which would be `std::map<Key, MappedType>::value_type` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yep, you're right. my definition does not hold. But i found a new one with your and Nole Ksums (the guy who answered) help posted below

Comment: @RemyLebeau that is not how it is implemented, at least on GCC/libstdc++. It is the size of `std::_Rb_tree_node<const Key, MappedType>`, as seen in the answer below. This struct is much bigger as it contains 32 extra bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find anywhere in the C++ standard a statement that affirms clearly how `max_size()` can be calculated.

On GCC/libstdc++ implementation, `max_size` is defined on `include/bits/stl_map.h` as

```cpp
      /** Returns the maximum size of the %map.  */
      size_type
      max_size() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { return _M_t.max_size(); }
```

where `_M_t` is of type `std::_Rb_tree` and defines `max_size()` in `include/bits/stl_tree.h` as

```cpp
      size_type
      max_size() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { return _Alloc_traits::max_size(_M_get_Node_allocator()); }
```

So this says this limit is basically the maximum number of elements that the allocator itself can create.

The `_Alloc_traits::max_size` is defined in `include/bits/alloc_traits.h` as

```cpp
    typedef std::allocator_traits<_Alloc> _Base_type;
    ...
    using _Base_type::max_size;
```

Of course the allocator is whatever you use in your container but the default implementation boils down to `include/ext/new_allocator.h`:

```cpp
size_type max_size() const
{
    return size_t(__PTRDIFF_MAX__) / sizeof(_Tp);
}
```

The above was cleaned up a bit for macros etc.

Type type `_Tp` is defined as `std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, int> >`, which is basically

```cpp
struct _Rb_tree_node {
    struct __aligned_membuf<std::pair<const int, int> > _M_storage;
    ...
    // from _Rb_tree_node_base 
    _Rb_tree_color  _M_color;
    _Base_ptr       _M_parent;
    _Base_ptr       _M_left;
    _Base_ptr       _M_right;
};
```

So for `std::map<int32_t,int32_t>` that will be 40 bytes - 3 pointers at 8 bytes plus 4 bytes color plus 4 bytes padding plus 8 bytes of the `std::pair`.

which means this is the theoretical maximum possible you can ever have regardless of amount of memory or any other limiting factors.

Godbolt test: https://godbolt.org/z/vME5qvTGP

Comment: Hello @Nole Ksum thank you for the answer, your insights were very helpful! With knowing now that each Node consists of 32 bytes + the size of the corresponding pair i found you can calculate max size with the following line: (ssize_t(-1) / (sizeof(typename std::map<Key, mapped_type>::value_type) + 32)), atleast for linux this works. Thank you